# Unable to install Nvidia driver version > 470 on Ubuntu 20.04 MATE desktop

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, mate

Running Ubuntu 20.04 with MATE desktop installed. Nvidia driver version 470 works ok, but some Steam games complain and want a version > 499.

When I install any Nvidia driver version > 500 using ***Software & Updates / Additional Drivers***, it appears to install correctly, but upon reboot, I experience a "login loop" i.e., after entering my password, the screen flashes and then shows the login screen again.

How can I install a version of the driver > 499 on the MATE desktop in 20.04?

Answer (score 1):

"marco", the window manager used in the MATE desktop, has a problem interacting with the newer Nvidia drivers due to something called Xpresent. The result is that the xserver crashes and results in the login loop.

The problem has been patched in 22.04, but not in 20.04.  However, there is a ppa that provides a version of "marco" with Xpresent support removed.  Adding this ppa to my system and building in the patched "marco" packages allowed me to install Nvidia driver version 525.

The ppa is here: [https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mate-dev/+archive/ubuntu/marco](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-mate-dev/+archive/ubuntu/marco)

`apt-policy marco` output after incorporating the ppa:

```
$ apt policy marco
marco:
  Installed: 1.24.0-1ubuntu2
  Candidate: 1.24.0-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 1.24.0-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mate-dev/marco/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.24.0-1ubuntu1 500
        500 ssh://[local mirror address redacted]/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
```